# How to make a local string variable in Lisp?

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to make a local string variable and build the string with variables.

```
(setq string-label (make-array 0 :element-type `character
                                 :fill-pointer 0
                                 :adjustable t))
(loop while (and (char/= char #\Space)
                 (char/= char #\()
                 (char/= char #\Newline))
      do
         (vector-push-extend char string-label)
         (setq char (read-char fstream nil)))
```

I am getting an error:

```
*** - SETQ: variable STRING_LABEL has no value
```

Comment: STRING_LABEL has an underscore. Where does that come from?

Comment: See `make-string`. Example: `(make-string 8 :initial-element #\o)`. Also `make-string` and `fill <sequence> <character>`.

Comment: STRING_LABEL was a typo. It should have been string-label. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the code you are running is different than the code you've given, as there's no reference to `string_label` in that code.

However there are enough other problems with the code you've shown to make it worth fixing.  These are essentially

- you should not bind variables, let alone local variables, by assigning to them, and in fact doing so is not legal in CL – instead you should use a binding form like `let` (in the code below I'm using `loop` to do the binding for me);
- you are using `char` before it is bound (and even then, it's not actually bound since you just use `setq`);
- the termination condition for reading the label is not right – if you hit EOF you'll get an error since `char` will then be `nil`.

Additionally there's some unclarity in your code: when you hit one of the 'stopper' characters, do you want to leave that as the next character to be read?  My version assumes that you do.  This has implications for successive calls to the function, of course: you need to skip forward over stoppers.

So, here is a cleaned-up version of your code, presented as a function.  This also makes the list of 'stopper' characters an argument to the function, and uses `member` to know when to stop (`member` uses `eql` by default, and `eql` is the same as `char=` on characters, so this is fine).

```
(defun read-string-label (fstream &key (stoppers '(#\Space #\( #\Newline)))
  (loop with string-label = (make-array 0 :element-type 'character
                                        :fill-pointer 0
                                        :adjustable t)
        for char =  (read-char fstream nil)
        while (and char (not (member char stoppers)))
        do (vector-push-extend char string-label)
        finally (progn
                  (when char
                    ;; push the stopper character back into the stream
                    ;; so it's the next thing we read
                    (unread-char char fstream))
                  (return string-label))))
```

Answer (score 4):

The primary constructs for defining local variables are `let` and `let*`. Other operators derived from `let` also bind local variables, such as `with-open-file` and `destructuring-bind`. Of course `lambda` and function definition forms derived from it like `defun` have parameters, and those are local variables. (Historically, `lambda` existed before `let`).

In the `loop` construct, local variables may be defined using the `with` clause, as in:

```
;; Like a hidden (let ((x 42) ...) in the code generated by loop:

(loop with x = 42 ...)
```

This allows many instances of `loop` to avoid being surrounded by an extra `let`, and thus appearing more "tidy".

Local variables may also be automatically stepped across the iterations of a `loop`, which in many cases can avoid the incorporation of clunky `setq` assignment forms, if the logic is worked right:

```
;; x is initially 1, then 2, 3, ...

(loop with x = 1 then (+ 1 x) ...)
```

Global variables in Common Lisp are defined using `defvar` and `defparameter`, not by simply assigning with `setf` or `setq`.

The effect of simply issuing a `setf` or `setq` on a variable that has previously not been defined is subject to an unfortunate "gray area" of ANSI Lisp, and behaves differently on different implementations due to different interpretations of that gray area.

In some implementations, `setq` on an undefined variable produces a diagnostic. On others, it creates a special variable, similarly to `defparameter`, and on others still, it creates something resembling a "global lexical" variable: the symbol receives a binding, but isn't marked as a special variable, remaining available for lexical binding.